# Pass the selected segment in UISegmentControl to a DetailViewController for Editing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I seem to be missing something very simple here.

I have a `UIViewController` which contains a `UISegmentControl` with two segments (*"shown" & "not shown"*).
The user selects one in this view controller and fills in some information into text fields which all gets saved to a table view controller.
When I click on a cell to edit the information, I can't get the selected segment to show, so if I select "Not shown" in this cell when saving, I want it to show "Not Shown" selected when I edit the cell.

I then of course want to provide the user the ability to change from "Not Shown" to "Shown" with the `UISegmentControl`.

My code for saving the UISegment Control in the save method of the creating View Controller is:

```
contract.wasShown = @(self.isShownSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0);
```

I'm using Core Data here.

So in the detailViewController, I have tried a few things but with no luck (it's always showing the first segment).

```
if ([contract.wasShown boolValue]) {
    contract.wasShown = @(self.isShownSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0);
}
else {
    contract.wasShown = @(self.isShownSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1);
}
```

What do I need to do to get the selected segment shown and then what should I put in the save method of the Detail View to change that selection if possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all - this was just me being stupid.

Implemented with the following code in viewDidLoad:

```
if ([contract.wasShown boolValue])
    {
         self.isShownSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        self.isShownSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;

    }
```